# How to create a fake "YouTube-Bar" with a range from 1 (=negative) to 10 (=positive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, range

**What I want to do:**

I want to create a fake "YouTube bar" where my visitors can see how their ingroup has (allegedly) rated something. This "YouTube bar" should have a range between 1 = very negative to 10 = very positive.

**What I've got so far:**

It was no problem to create a "YouTube bar" where the range is between 0 = very negative and 10 = very positive (whereas 5 = neutral/middle point). In this case, I have got eleven numbers (from 0 to 10). But I am struggeling with converting the range to 1-10 (whereas 5.5 should be the middle point and I only got 10 numbers).

I know it should work with basic mathematics (maybe divide the random number by 100/11 und multiply it by 100/10?) but I'm feeling a little bit stupid for not figuring it out. This is my code so far (http://jsfiddle.net/AauvC/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="youtubeFake">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> My Group Rating:</td>
        <td id="ownNumber"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="youtubeBar"> 
            <div id="ownLeft"></div>
            <div id="ownRight"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#youtubeFake{
    width: 60%;
}

.youtubeBar {
    width: 60%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#ownLeft{
    background-color: green;
    height: 4px;
    float: left;
}

#ownRight{
    background-color: red;
    height: 4px;
    float: right;
}

#ownNumber,{
    text-align: right;
}
```

**JQuery/Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ownPercentage = (Math.random()*90)+10;       //create random number between 10 - 100
    $('#ownLeft').width(ownPercentage + '%');        //left part of the bar (the green part)
    $('#ownRight').width(100-ownPercentage + '%');   //right part of the bar (the red part)
    document.getElementById('ownNumber').innerHTML = (ownPercentage/10).toFixed(1);   //write random number into the HTML document and divide it by 10 (so I have a number between 1-10 instead of 10-100)
});
```

I would be glad if you guys could give me a hint!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Change the range from 0-10 to 1-10. That means if the width of the green line is in the middle (=50%), it should show the number "5.5" (the middle number between 1-10). If the width of the green line is 0% (it's not showing), it should show the number "1". If the width of the green line is 100%, it should show the number "10".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normalize the number by getting the percentage of `ownPercentage` out of `90` (your total number (`100`) minus your start number (`10`)) and then multiplying by your total number (`100`):

```
var ownPercentage = (Math.random()*90)+10;
var ownPercentageWidth = ((ownPercentage - 10) / 90) * 100;
$('#ownLeft').width(ownPercentageWidth + '%');
$('#ownRight').width(100-ownPercentageWidth + '%');
```

`10` would give `0%` width, `55` would give `50%` width and `100` would give `100%` width.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AauvC/1/).

if `ownPercentage` was `10`, this would give:

```
> ((10 - 10) / 90) * 100
> (0 / 90) * 100
> 0 * 100
> 0
```

..and if it was `55`:

```
> ((55 - 10) / 90) * 100
> (45 / 90) * 100
> 0.5 * 100
> 50
```

..and if it was `100`:

```
> ((100 - 10) / 90) * 100
> (90 / 90) * 100
> 1 * 100
> 100
```

Comment: Ah, this works perfectly (and it looks so simple!). Thanks a lot (+ for explaining the math, too)!